# How many volumes should I add in my btrfs?

Tags: linux, nas, ps, btrfs

How much overhead does a single physical partition add to a btrfs volume?

```
ps aux | grep btrfs | wc -l
```

results in 102. I have 4TBx4 in my NAS and 16GB RAM and Core i3 processor. The NAS also hosts a plex server, gitlab, apache server and is a development machine sometimes.

I keep adding 100GB of disk space from each drive to my btrfs volumes (/usr /tmp /home /var/cache /var) when they run out. Is this a poor practice? Am I abusing btrfs?

```
root       919  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-worker-1]
root       920  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-genwork-1]
root       921  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-submit-1]
root       922  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-delalloc-]
root       923  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-fixup-1]
root       924  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-1]
root       925  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root       926  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-rmw-1]
root       927  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-rai]
root       928  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root       930  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-freespace]
root       931  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-delayed-m]
root       932  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-cache-1]
root       933  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-readahead]
root       934  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-flush_del]
root       935  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-qgroup-re]
root       936  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-cleaner]
root       937  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-transacti]
root       946  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-genwork-1]
root       947  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-submit-1]
root       948  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-delalloc-]
root       949  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-fixup-1]
root       952  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-rmw-1]
root       953  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-rai]
root       954  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root       956  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-freespace]
root       957  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-delayed-m]
root       958  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-cache-1]
root       959  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-readahead]
root       960  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-flush_del]
root       961  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-qgroup-re]
root       996  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-cleaner]
root       997  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-transacti]
root      1001  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-worker-1]
root      1002  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-genwork-1]
root      1003  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-submit-1]
root      1004  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-delalloc-]
root      1005  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-fixup-1]
root      1007  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root      1008  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-rmw-1]
root      1009  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-rai]
root      1010  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root      1011  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-wri]
root      1012  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-freespace]
root      1013  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-delayed-m]
root      1014  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-cache-1]
root      1015  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-readahead]
root      1016  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-flush_del]
root      1017  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-qgroup-re]
root      1023  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-cleaner]
root      1024  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-transacti]
root      1035  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-genwork-1]
root      1036  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-submit-1]
root      1037  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-delalloc-]
root      1038  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-fixup-1]
root      1040  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root      1041  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-rmw-1]
root      1042  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-rai]
root      1043  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root      1045  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-freespace]
root      1046  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-delayed-m]
root      1047  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-cache-1]
root      1048  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-readahead]
root      1049  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-flush_del]
root      1050  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-qgroup-re]
root      1051  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-cleaner]
root      1052  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:01 [btrfs-transacti]
root      1093  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-genwork-1]
root      1094  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-submit-1]
root      1095  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-delalloc-]
root      1096  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-fixup-1]
root      1098  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root      1099  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-rmw-1]
root      1100  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-rai]
root      1101  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root      1103  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-freespace]
root      1104  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-delayed-m]
root      1105  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-cache-1]
root      1106  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-readahead]
root      1107  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-flush_del]
root      1108  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-qgroup-re]
root      1109  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-cleaner]
root      1110  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-transacti]
root      2108  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-2]
root      2680  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:32   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root      2911  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:33   0:00 [btrfs-endio-wri]
root      2964  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:33   0:00 [btrfs-endio-wri]
root      2987  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    03:34   0:00 [btrfs-worker-2]
root      4020  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:09   0:00 [btrfs-endio-wri]
root      9104  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:40   0:00 [btrfs-worker-3]
root     12973  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    05:20   0:00 [btrfs-endio-3]
root     13663  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:36   0:00 [btrfs-endio-wri]
root     13940  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:38   0:00 [btrfs-endio-met]
root     13958  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    10:38   0:00 [btrfs-endio-2]
user     14067  0.0  0.0  11748   920 pts/0    S+   10:38   0:00 grep --color=auto btrfs
root     19930  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:36   0:00 [btrfs-endio-2]
root     20046  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:36   0:00 [btrfs-endio-2]
root     20063  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:36   0:00 [btrfs-endio-wri]
root     20253  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    06:37   0:00 [btrfs-worker-6]
```